# Sorting posts on a WordPress site with custom SQL

Tags: sql, wordpress

I have a php function that generates a comma separated list of Post IDs that specify the order those posts should display on my WordPress site.

I'm looking for a place I can insert an SQL query like:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE ID IN ('1', '2', '3')
```

Which .php file should I modify?  How should I phrase the SQL?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? In what template file do you want to use that? Is it a static page or a category page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off you should use [`wp_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for this. It is designed to query posts.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post__in' => array ( 1,2,3) //the Ids
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($query->have_posts()){
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        echo get_the_ID().'<br/>';
    }

} else {
    echo 'no posts found';
}
```

**About the placement**
I advise to do it in a [custom template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates), make a simple template with the code above, create a page assign it that template and make the page private.

Answer (score 3):

Paste your php function in file (root wordpress folder)/wp-content/themes/(name of your theme)/functions.php
SQL query should be like.

```
$sql=$wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE ID IN ('1', '2', '3');");
$results=$wpdb->get_results($sql);          
echo ">>>>".$result[0]->something."<br />";//blah blah...
```

WoW,i did not mention $wpdp as global,still code was working fine on my system!,anyways 
i would suggest you write "global $wpdb" in your function.

Now the main question is from where should you call this function;
you have to call it from theme/(your theme)/index.php

Try figuring out how the posts are generated in your current theme,and you might get what you need to do!

Answer (score 1):

```
global $wpdb; $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE ID IN (1, 2, 3) ORDER BY ID");
```

You can use that in your theme's functions.php file.

Comment: I don't see any SQL in my theme's functions.php file or additional_functions.php, however, I do see a bunch in the wp-includes/functions.php file.  Which block would I modify that into?  The closest candidate looks like it's in the function `do_enclose()`.

Comment: It doesn't matter, dude.  You can use SQL anywhere you want in PHP, as long as you have a connection, which you do, because you have the $wpdb object.

Comment: You SHOULD use it in functions.php, and you should definitely NOT modify the wp-includes folder at all.